# How can I create a fingerprint authentication login without using android's fingerprintmanager?

Tags: java, android

I was about to create a college project which would use fingerprint for login but the only problem is that i am prohibited from using android's fingerprint manager. So if anyone could guide me how could I achieve it I would be very thankful.

I searched for a while but all I could find was everyone used the fingerprint manager class.

Comment: Why on earth would you be prohibited from using the fingerprint manager? That's a horrible requirement if that's been put onto you by your teacher.

Comment: I guess he assumed you write your own fingerprint manager... that's tough

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`BiometricPrompt`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/biometrics/BiometricPrompt.html)? It's a new class introduced in API 28 (Android 9) that's meant to supersede `FingerprintManager`, which has been deprecated to allow hardware vendors to display their own biometrics dialogs.

Of course, because it was only introduced in API 28, if you're developing against an older version of Android then you're out of luck there. Frankly, a restriction on using a standard Android class like `FingerprintManager` is outlandish, to say the least. The reason why you don't see any examples of a fingerprint authentication system that doesn't use `FingerprintManager` is because Android already provides a robust and secure fingerprint authentication system as standard through that class, so there's no need to re-invent the wheel. In fact, rolling your own fingerprint system will almost always be a bad idea, because there's a near-zero chance that it will be as throughly tested for vulnerabilities as the standard Android class has.

I would suggest clarifying with your teacher why this isn't allowed, and if they won't budge on the restriction, see what they suggest as a workaround.

Comment: Note that the current default implementation of `BiometricPrompt` is basically a wrapper around `FingerprintManager` (though it calls a hidden overload of `FingerprintManager.authenticate` which takes a couple of extra parameters to trigger the prompt to be shown).